# Does the null article apply to the function or role of something other than a person?

Tags: article, grammaticality

I have looked at the material here and elsewhere on when to use the null article but I still don't entirely understand it. One of the rules listed on a website about [the usage of german articles](https://web.archive.org/web/20040103035025/http://alou.mordor.sk/germanistika/Artikel.htm) refers to "Funktion" i.e. role.

But does this refer only to a person's role, e.g.

> Ich diene als Stellvertreter

or can it be the role of a thing, e.g. to say that tradition serves as a stabilizing force  in society?

> Tradition dient als stabilisierender Einfluß

Comment: Ich keine Sprachregel, in der es einen Unterschied macht, ob von einer Person oder einer Sache die Rede ist. Selbst semantische Regeln (Heinz verantwortet sich vor Gericht) werden im Märchen (Das Schwein fällte den Richterspruch) oder Bericht aus dem LSD-Rausch (Die Gardine erhob Anklage) aufgehoben. Mit "Es dient als Stellvertreter" kann man eine Googlesuche starten, um die Vermutung zu prüfen, da "Es" selten für Personen Anwendung findet (Ausnahmen: Mädchen, Weib, Mitglied, ...).

Comment: It's very misleading to portray this as a rule depending on "Funktion". "als Stellvertreter dienen" is correct, but "in der Rolle Stellvertreters dienen" is incorrect. It's really more a rule about the specific word "als" than about any general considerations.

Comment: "Ich `kenne` keine Sprachregel" ... hätte es oben heißen sollen. Pardon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The noun *Funktion* that you fond in that rule on the linked website in fact really refers to the office or role of a person. (I use the sign *ø* to mark a null article. Of course in fact there should be nothing.)

> Peter ist *ø* Kassier des Gartenzwergevereins.
>   Peter is (the) treasurer of the garden dwarf association.

Being the treasurer or cashier of a little hobby club is not a profession, its just what is called *»eine Funktion«* in German. The best way to translate this word might be *office, role* or just *function*.

The rule that you found says, that you don't use an article (i.e. you use a null article) together with:

- **Beruf** (profession)

  > Peter ist *ø* Tischler.
  >   Peter is a carpenter.
- **Funktion** (office, role)

  > Peter ist *ø* Kassier.
  >   Peter is a cashier.
- **Nationalität** (nationlity)

  > Peter ist *ø* Österreicher.
  >   Peter is an Austrian.
- **Weltanschaung** (weltanschauung, ideology, philosophy of life)

  > Peter ist *ø* Atheist.
  >   Peter is an atheist.

But this is just one rule out of eleven general rules and six additional rules about names, titles etc. Other rules deal with nouns that apply not to persons. You have to obey all of those rules.

Just to make it more complicated. This all is correct too:

> Peter ist ein Tischler.
>   Peter ist ein Kassier.
>   Peter ist ein Österreicher.
>   Peter ist ein Atheist.

And, if there is just one carpenter, cashier etc. among a bigger goup of people, also this is possible:

> Peter ist der Tischler.
>   Peter ist der Kassier.
>   Peter ist der Österreicher.
>   Peter ist der Atheist.

---

btw:
You are using the verb *»dienen«* wrong in your examples. In German you don't say *I serve as XY*. You say *I am XY*. You only use non-living objects in this construction:

> A dient als B = A is used as (a/the) B.
>   Die Fassade dient als Projektionsfläche.
>   The facade is used as a projection surface.

but:

> A serves as B = A ist (ein(e)) B.
>   Peter serves as deputy.
>   Peter ist (ein/der) Stellvertreter.
>   wrong: <del>Peter dient als Stellvertreter.</del>

Comment: "A serves as B" kann man auch mit "A dient als B" übersetzen, IMO, z.B:. "Here, A serves as scapegoat for the media" => "A dient hier als Sündenbock der Medien", wobei "dient" hier sowas wie eine (in diesem Fall erzwungene) Funktion andeutet. Das gilt natürlich nicht für richtige Berufe oder Funktionen, wie "deputy". Obwohl... Man kann natürlich sagen, dass Gesetzesvertreter (dem Volke) dienen.

Comment: Man kann auch sagen, dass in meinem Vorbild "dienen" was Ähnliches bedeutet wie "wird benutzt als".

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: »A dient jemandem« (»James dient dem Earl of Sandwich«) ist aber auch eine andere Konstruktion als »A dient als B« (»Dieser Satz dient als Beispiel«). In ersten Fall führt eine Person aktiv eine Tätigkeit aus, die als Dienstleistung zu bezeichnen ist. Im zweiten Fall hat etwas eine passive Funktion inne, ohne selbst irgend etwas aktiv zu tun.

Comment: Klar, aber beides ist "to serve as" in English. "To serve", ohne "as" gibt es auch. und dan bedeutet es wirklich dienen, wie in deinem Vorbild mit dem Earl. Man kann sogar sagen "He serves the town of Dawson Creek as deputy." <g>

Answer (score 0):

It does not really matter if it is a person or thing.

Example for a thing:

> Citronensäure wird als Säuerungsmittel verwendet.